# How many ordered pairs of integers, $(m, n)$, satisfy \[ 5m^2 + 9n^2 = 1234567? \]

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

How many ordered pairs of integers, $(m, n)$, satisfy

$
5m^2 + 9n^2 = 1234567?
$

I started by trying to just solve the equation but ended up with either $m$ in terms of $n$ or $n$ in terms of $m$. I was unable to find pairs of $(m, n)$ consistantly using any method I know, and i don't know if its possible to get integer solutions only with a simple method.

How can I find integer solutions only in a simple way?

Comment: Hint: Look modulo $5$ first.

Comment: Or modulo $3$ ...

Comment: 11234567 = 1 mod 9, but 5m**2 can only have values 0,5,2,8 mod 9

Comment: I do not think this equation has integer solutions. RHS is wrong number.

Answer (score 3):

None. Working mod $4$ suffices.

Note that exactly one of $n$, $m$ must be odd for $5m^2+9n^2$ to be odd. But as for any integer $x$, the resulting integer $x^2 \pmod 4$ is either $1$ or $0$, and thus, as both $5 \pmod 4 = 9 \pmod 4=1$, it follows that $5x^2 \pmod 4$ is either $1$ or $0$, and also, $9x^2 \pmod 4$ is either $1$ or $0$ as well.
So from this it follows that if $5m^2+9n^2$ is odd, then $5m^2 + 9n^2 \pmod 4$ must be $1$. But note that $1234567 \pmod 4$ is $3$, so....